# Where can I get a good description about windows build-in exe programs like wupdmgr.exe?

Tags: windows, malware, static-analysis

I was checking the Strings for Lab01-04.exe from Practical Malware Analysis and I found wupdmgr.exe and I face this every time I search for an exe.
Is there any "msdn" alike repository but for exe files?

Comment: if you google for it doesn't it give you the description what the tool does?

Comment: It does, but every time it shows results from different websites, I was thinking of one reliable source!

Comment: @AhmadKouraiem Sadly Microsoft still values security by obscurity in some parts. Sadly, they bought SysInternals who did quiet a bit of recon